# Inline assembly in c to get current time, username and machine name

Tags: c, inline-assembly

I want to write a function for my custom shell which prints out the current time, username and machine name as a prompt. I want to do this using inline assembly in c on linux. So far my code is:

```
uint64_t msr;
asm volatile ( "rdtsc\n\t"    // Returns the time in EDX:EAX.
               "shl $32, %%rdx\n\t"  // Shift the upper bits left.
               "or %%rdx, %0"        // 'Or' in the lower bits.
               : "=a" (msr)
               :
               : "rdx");
```

I have only gotten this far and not attempted to write code for username and machine name. The problem is this code doesn't want to compile using the gcc compiler, it prints an

> error: impossible register constraint in `asm'
>
> confused by earlier errors, bailing out

I have found this code as an example here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate

The question is how can I write code in inline assembly to get me current time, username and machine name?

Comment: Are you sure your gcc is compiling for x86-64?  That code looks correct (but unnecessary; [Get CPU cycle count?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13772567)).  That error message would make sense for `gcc -m32` where a 64-bit integer couldn't fit in EAX.

Comment: I want to write a prompt for my custom shell, it should look like '16:34 user17@student#' - 16:34 being time, user17 being username, @student being machine name

Comment: Ok, again why asm?  And why *inline* asm instead of writing a whole function in a separate asm file?  Anyway, getting the right scale factor to scale TSC ticks to seconds is hard, and getting the right offset to map that to absolute time of day requires interaction with the OS.  It's vastly easier to ask the OS what time it is with `clock_gettime()`, which will internally use RDTSC in userspace without the performance hit of a system call.  You also need to decide *how* you want to get username and machine name, either from env vars or system calls; the CPU doesn't know about those.

Comment: Why are you complicating things? Why not just write C code and use proper POSIX functions or Linux system calls or whatever else is available?

Comment: I wanted to use inline assembly because I have found it as a possible solution, but seeing as Linux system calls are a possible solution as well, I will use those.